# Why is PageMethods object undefined?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, pagemethods

I've read several answers to similar questions and none of them answer my question. I've tried everything I can think of. Here's what my code looks like:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMgr" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server" onblur="textboxOnBlur()"></asp:TextBox>
<script>
     function onSuccess() {
        alert("success");
    }

    function onFailure() {
        alert("failure");
    }

    function textboxOnBlur() {
        PageMethods.CheckDBForCodes(onSuccess, onFailure);
        //alert("test");
    }

</script>
```

Here's the server-side function that should be called by `PageMethods`:

```
 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Protected Shared Sub CheckDBForCodes() 
    `search DB for codes
End Sub
```

For some reason, I'm still getting the error message that says that PageMethods is undefined. As you can see, the `textboxOnBlur` function is called when you click away from the textbox. Am I missing something?

Comment: For a start, shouldn't the `<WebMethod>` be `<PageMethod>`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm not sure. I haven't seen anything on `<PageMethod>`.

Comment: OK, scratch that idea, it was just in the first [tutorial](http://metasapiens.com/pagemethods/intro.aspx) I found. I see that `<WebMethod>` is used in most of the other tutorials.

Comment: At first, I thought it was because the `ScriptManager` I was using was actually on the Master Page. But I removed it from the Master Page and put it on the actual web page and it did the same thing. I'm stumped.

Comment: You might find [ASP.NET Validation Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx) suitable instead of creating your own. Which is perhaps only avoiding the problem, or it might be just what you need.

Comment: Um, are you using [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)? It could be that something is out of scope, in which case that will inform you of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the `PageMethods` object was undefined was because the access modifier to the server side function was set to `Protected`. I changed it to `Public` and all was well with the world.